# Bound of a vector * matrix * vector product in terms of eigenvalue and vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Assume $x$ and $y$ are [nx1] column vectors and $\textbf{A}$ is a [nxn] symmetric matrix.

The minimum and maximum eigenvalues of the matrix $\textbf{A}$ are $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$.

The vector-norm operator $\lVert \cdot \lVert$ in this case means vector two-norm.

Q1. How the bound of $\left\lVert \textbf{A}x \right\lVert$ is derived? Is the inequality equation below right? If it is right, how can it be derived?
$$
\lambda_{min} \left\lVert x \right\lVert \leq
\left\lVert \textbf{A} x \right\lVert \leq \lambda_{max} \left\lVert x \right\lVert
$$

Q2. How about the bound of $\left| x^{T} \textbf{A} y \right|$? Is the inequality equation below correct?
$$
\lambda_{min} \left\lVert x \right\lVert \left\lVert y \right\lVert \leq
\left| x^{T} \textbf{A} y \right| \leq \lambda_{max} \left\lVert x \right\lVert
\left\lVert y \right\lVert
$$

Comment: If $x,y$ are column-vectors, then $xAy$ does not make sense. Presumably, you mean $x^\top Ay$. Also, since $x^\top Ay$ is a scalar, it would be $|x^\top Ay |$ rather than $\|x^\top A y\|$.

Comment: Your question as it currently stands lacks context and therefore does not meet [the expectations of this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please edit your question to tell us a bit more. For a start, it would help if you could answer these questions: Where are these inequalities coming from? That is, were you asked about these directly, or is this some guess that you've arrived at on your own? What have you tried so far? Have you learned about the "singular value decomposition" of a matrix?

Comment: Also, these inequalities make me think that you're actually considering symmetric matrices (i.e. matrices with $A^T = A$). If that is the case, please make this clear

Comment: Also, if you do address these suggestions, please do so by [edit]ing this information into your question rather than by leaving comments.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your comments. The equation needs to be corrected.

I have seen some answers that say the right part of the inequality equation of Q1 is correct. But I wanted to know how it can be derived. And if the inequality equation of Q1 is correct, I wanted to know if the inequality equation of Q2 is also correct. 

According to your answer, I think I have to try to get answer by "single value decomposition" of a matrix. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: As I said, this context should be edited into your question rather than simply stated in a comment. The singular value decomposition is only necessary for getting inequalities like these for non-symmetric $A$; for a symmetric matrix $A$ the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) (and spectral decomposition) is the better tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These inequalities are incorrect as stated.

For an arbitrary matrix $A$, something like the first inequality can be framed in terms of the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). If $A$ has singular values $\sigma_1 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n$, then
$$
\sigma_n\|x\| \leq \|Ax\| \leq \sigma_1\|x\|.
$$
If $A$ is symmetric (or more generally if $A$ is normal), then
$$
\sigma_1 = \max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of $A$}\}, \quad 
\sigma_n = \min\{|\lambda|:\lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of $A$}\}.
$$
If $A$ is positive semidefinite (symmetric with non-negative eigenvalues), then it is indeed the case that $\sigma_1 = \lambda_\min$ and $\sigma_n = \lambda_\max$.

There is no general lower bound for $|x^TAy|$ except for $|x^TAy| \geq 0$. However, we do have the upper bound
$$
|x^TAy| \leq \sigma_1 \|x\|\,\|y\|.
$$

---

The following inequality (sometimes referred to as the "Rayleigh-Ritz theorem") is related to the first inequality. In general, for a symmetric matrix $M$, we have
$$
\lambda_\min(M) \|x\|^2 \leq x^TMx \leq \lambda_\max(M) \|x\|^2.
$$
The first inequality emerges when you use the fact that $\|Ax\|^2 = x^T(A^TA)x$ and apply the above to the matrix $M = A^TA$, which is symmetric with positive eigenvalues.